# Passing the data for ajax validation before submitting the form

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

This is my first question here so apologies for any logic errors, etc. I'm working on budget manager webapp, allowing the user to save his incomes and expenses data. Here specifically is an area for the user to create a custom category for either of those two. I'm trying to validate input data before submitting it, using ajax and php, the function is not working however. My aim was to check whether the category already exists in database. Please find my code below:

options.html

```
<div class="row gap-2 mt-3 mx-3" id="addCategory">  
  <button class="btn btn-success" onclick="addCategoryHandler('income')" 
  id="addIncomeCategory">Add new category</button> 
</div>

<form id="editForm" action="javascript:addCategory()">  
  <label id="cattegoryNameLabel" for="categoryName">Category Name</label>
  <input class="form-control inputBox errorCategory" type="text" id="categoryName" name="categoryName" aria-label="Nazwa kategorii"
  aria-describedby="cattegoryNameLabel"> 
</form>

jquery validation:

$(document).ready(function() {

  $('#editForm').validate({
     rules: {
       categoryName: {
       required: true,
       minlength: 3,
       maxlength: 20,
       categoryRegex: true,
       remote: '/settings/validate-category'
        },
    },
});
```

After pressing the button the code is being handled via Javascript and then an according modal is being displayed:

settings.js

```
function addCategoryHandler(newCategoryType) {
  categoryType = newCategoryType;

  //Set proper modal title
  $('#editModalLabel').text(addCategoryModalTitle);
  //Reset category name & limit input
  $('#categoryName').val('');
  $('#limit').val(parseFloat(0).toFixed(2));
  $('#limitCheck').prop( "checked", false );
  //Set proper button function
  $('#editForm').attr('action', "javascript:addCategory()");

  switchLimitForm();

  $('#editModal').modal('show');
}

function addCategory() {

  categoryName = $('#categoryName').val();
  categoryLimit = $('#limit').val();
  categoryLimitState = $('#limitCheck').is(':checked');

  $.ajax({
     type: 'POST',
     url: '/settings/addCategory',
     dataType: 'json',
     data: {
        postCategoryType: categoryType,
        postCategoryName: categoryName,
        postCategoryLimitState: categoryLimitState,
        postCategoryLimit: categoryLimit
      },

        success: function(result) {
          addCategoryRow(categoryName, result);
            
      },

        error: function(xhr){
            console.log(xhr);
        }
    });
}
```

The data is later passed to the controller, Settings.php:

```
public function validateCategoryAction()
  {
  $isEqual = ! $this->validateNewIncomeCategory($_GET['categoryName'], $_GET['ignore_id'] ?? null);

 header('Content-Type: application/json');
 echo json_encode($isEqual);
 }
    
 public function validateNewIncomeCategoryAction($name, $ignore_id = null)
 {
   $categories = Finance::getUserIncomeCategories();
        
   $name = 'Inne';

   if($categories)
    {
     $isEqual = true;
     foreach ($categories as $category)
        {
         if (strtolower($category['name']) == strtolower($name)) {
            $isEqual = false;
        }
    }
    return $isEqual;
    }
}
```

Database is being checked in the model, Finance.php:

```
public static function getUserIncomeCategories() 
    {
        $db = static::getDB();

        $query = $db->prepare('SELECT id, name FROM incomes_category_assigned_to_users WHERE user_id = :user_id');
        $query->bindValue(':user_id', $_SESSION['user_id'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $query->execute();
        return $query->fetchAll();
    }
```

My biggest concern for now is that the categoryName is not being passed to the Controller (as the form has not been submitted yet). The validation process on server side is fine but I want to set it for client's side as well. I was thinking about passing the data using Cookies, I do not know how to do it properly however. Also, sorry for such a long post, there are just lots of things going on here and it's been bugging me for a while. I'd appreciate any help.

Comment: If I understand your code, you send data via Ajax Post to url: '/settings/addCategory This seems an API. Have you a file without extension? Or have you an API?

Comment: Hi, here's my full code: https://github.com/Filip-92/budget-webpage-mvc/tree/feature-same_category